# Regex -> match a number between 000001 and 999999

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I'm on Linux and I need to do an expr in order to match
**6 digits** with this **range :
000001 to 999999**

I'm stuck with `'[0-9]{5}[1-9]'` but I can't match numbers which end with 0 like 000010
I was thinking about `'[0-9]{6}|?![0]{6}'` in order to eliminate "000000"

How can I use `?!` and/or are there any other solutions?

EDIT : solution =  `((?!000000)[0-9]{6})`

Comment: Are you using bash `=~` operator? What is the end goal?

Comment: It's not clear what you trying to do. You could try below answer if you are validating or you could try [`^(0{5}[1-9]|0{4}[1-9][0-9]|000[1-9][0-9]{2}|00[1-9][0-9]{3}|0[1-9][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{5})$`](https://regex101.com/r/0oIQ82/1)

Comment: `^(000001|000002|000003|...|999998|999999)$`  Filling in the `...` is left as an exercise.

Comment: What were you thinking about `?![0]{6}`? Did you mean like [`grep -P '^(?!0*$)\d{6}$'`](https://regex101.com/r/rRIWh2/1)

Comment: this will work [0-9]{5}[1-9]{1}

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: @AHT How about `000010`, the example given?

Comment: Please test your cases here regex101.com

Comment: Your own solution looks fine: `for s in $(seq -w 0 999999); do echo "$s"; done | grep -vP '^((?!000000)[0-9]{6})$'` only shows the banned `000000`. Please post it as an answer and remove the EDIT in the question. You can accept your own answer and others might vote for yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution =  `((?!000000)[0-9]{6})`

Answer (score 1):

Using regex to check if a number is in a range isn't optimal. Instead, you can check for your inputs length and if it is in the range, using

```
a=000001
if ((${#a} == 6 && a > 0 && a <= 999999));  then
  echo "foo"
fi
```